# Working with NSArray built with a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, nsarray

I need help with indexes and bounds.

I have an NSArray which contains a parsed file separated by « ; ».
So basically :

```
- (NSArray *) getArrayFromFile{
    NSArray *fileArray;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/list.txt", documentsDirectory];
    NSString *writedStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    fileArray = [writedStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    return fileArray;
}
```

I want to work with this array.

```
    NSArray* myArray = [self getArrayFromFile];
    for(k = 0; j < [myArray count]; k++){
        NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:k]);
    }
```

But when I run trough the returned NSArray, I always have a "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Here is the full error : http://pastebin.com/qApXU2s0 when the NSArray contains @"Hello",@"World",@"Array Content", and the original file "Hello;World;Array Content;"

Can someone help me with this ..?
Thank you!

Comment: > "when the NSArray contains @"Hello",@"World",@"Array Content""
Have you verified that the array actually does contain these entries, by inserting a breakpoint before the for loop?
your for loop initialises 'k', but the condition checks 'j'. This might be the only bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look at your for loop:

```
for(k = 0; j < [myArray count]; k++){
```

You can see that you're using a variable `k` in the first and third parts of the for statement, and a `j` in the middle part. So whatever `j` is, it's value is outside the bounds of your array. You'll want to change that `j` to a `k`. You could also change your for loop to do fast iteration, in which case you eliminate the `k` variable and you don't have the possibility of confusion like this.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but it's juste a mistype... :/

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you were right!! I'm feeling so stupid!

Answer (score 1):

What @Gavin said was 100% correct.. but a little tip for the future..

```
for (NSString *stringInArray in myArray) 
{ 
     NSLog(@"%@", stringInArray);
}
```

The above code snippet is a little nicer to work with.

Or, if you are feeling really brave, checkout [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock%3a)